# SELLECT * FROM Table WHERE name=$variable not working

Tags: mysql, select, where

I'm trying to set up a simple SQL Code to collect a users details when they log in to a new site I'm writing, but it throws an error every time. Any Ideas what. I'm doing wrong?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE uname = '".$uname."'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
  echo "Returned rows are: " . $result -> num_rows;
  // Free result set
  $result -> free_result();
} else {
  echo "<hr>Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Thee response I receive from the server is:

```
Error: SELECT * FROM Users WHERE uname = 'XYZ'
```

Comment: can you see what is returned by $conn->query($sql)? Might <> TRUE
refer https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_query.asp

Comment: I have change the code to ask it to display anything that's been found but it shows the same error.

Comment: the SQL is good. Query should return 0 rows, or more.

Comment: That's what I thought, but the contents of $result are empty.

Comment: is there content? remove the WHERE clause - return the whole table...

Comment: is PHP such that "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE uname = '".$uname."'" needs to be "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE uname = '" . $uname . "'" (spaces around the . ) :) ( . ) ( . ) :)

Comment: For successful queries which produce a result set, such as SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN, mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries, mysqli_query() will return true.  -- https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php
You are getting a result set - returns mysqli_result object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the PHP syntax is wrong.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
}

    // Perform query
    if ($result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE uname = '".$uname."'")) {
      echo "Returned rows are: " . mysqli_num_rows($result);
      // Free result set
      mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
    
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: is PHP such that "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE uname = '".$uname."'" needs to be "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE uname = '" . $uname . "'" (spaces around the . ) :) ( . ) ( . ) :)

Comment: Thank you so much.